# How to obtain vector of statistics from high dimensional 3d-array?

Tags: r, image-classification

I'm working in a project of images defects clustering. Each image is associated to a specific defect type ( And a 3d array of pixels using `readJPEG` ).

An example of images is the following :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO9XY.jpg

```
library(jpeg)
im <- readJPEG("C:/Users/Rayane_2/Desktop/Data/PCB1/PCB/PCB_USED/01.jpg")
dim(im)
[1] 1586 3034    3
```

The desired process is described as follow :

```
For each picture in specific directory :

1/ Convert the JPG picture to a 3d array ** ( RGB data of jpg image is a 3d array ). 

2/ Summarize that 3d array in a **vector** of statistics using a function like `stats()` . 

3/ Return this vector and continue to build a full clustering dataset.
```

I'm searching to convert `im[,,1]` , `im[,,2]` , `im[,,3]` as vectors `as.vector()`.

After that i need to extract some statistics , something like :

```
stats <-function(im){

return(c(min(as.vector(im[,,1])),max(as.vector(im[,,1])),sum(as.vector(im[,,1])),range(as.vector(im[,,1])),var(as.vector(im[,,1])), min(as.vector(im[,,2])),max(as.vector(im[,,2])),sum(as.vector(im[,,2])),range(as.vector(im[,,2])),var(as.vector(im[,,2])),min(as.vector(im[,,3])),max(as.vector(im[,,3])),sum(as.vector(im[,,3])),range(as.vector(im[,,3])),var(as.vector(im[,,3])))

}
```

There are possible solutions to obtain current statistics using r packages such `descr()` in `{summarytools}` , see [R statistics package](https://statsandr.com/blog/descriptive-statistics-in-r/#summary.)

**Because of `im` 3d-array high dimensions, the running is very slow**

```
dim(im)
[1] 1586 3034    3
```

Question :

I'm searching possible solutions , any other R functions / packages that can do such task in a very fast way ?

Thanks ,

Comment: You can just loop over the third dimenstion i.e. `apply(im, 3, \(x) c(min =min(x), max = max(x), sum = sum(x)))`

Comment: @akrun , nice to see you again. This gives the error > Error: unexpected input in "apply(im, 3, \"

Comment: You may have an older R version,  change the `\(x)` to `function(x)`

Comment: Do you want the summary statistics for all the 3034 columns separately? or just summary on the matrix 1586 x 3034 for each of the third dim

Comment: Exactly , i'm serching just summary on the matrix 1586 x 3034 for each of the third dim. Each of third level matrices represent one of following colors > Red , green , blue.

Comment: If you are reading all the files in the folder, then use `lapply` with `apply` i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(jpgfiles, function(file) apply(readJPEG(file), 3, function(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x), sum = sum(x))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could loop over the the third dimension with `apply` and `MARGIN = 3`

```
out <- apply(im, 3, function(x) c(min =min(x), max = max(x), sum = sum(x)))
```

If there are multiple files, read them into a `list` first

```
lst1 <- lapply(jpgfiles, function(file) apply(readJPEG(file), 3, 
      function(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x), sum = sum(x))))
```